# Facebook App Page missing "Go To App"

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I have a facebook "app" (an external site with Facebook Connect) called Mutuality and it properly links to Facebook "App Page" http://www.facebook.com/mutuality.org

At first http://www.facebook.com/mutuality.org had a nice "Go To App" link.
But after editing some page info it is coming up in search as an "Organization" page rather than an "App Page" and whatever I do I can't get the "Go To App" button back!

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the page category has to be  Brands & Product / App page - don't change that!
Working now at http://www.facebook.com/pages/Mutuality/254370917995739